# MVC3 project has Ajax calls failed after deploying to IIS7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have read almost all of the questions on this, but found no solution. The error I got is `500 Internal Service Error` which points to a specific error: `CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context.`

The strange thing is this error only occurs when an `ajax` call is made.  When there is no ajax call involved, the same `cshtml` page works fine.

Here are the two responses with one that works(first) and the other fails(second):

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:7033
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 10 Feb 2014 19:25:49 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0




Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
quarter:1
year:1
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:48466
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 10 Feb 2014 19:28:29 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

Please help!

Comment: As you may have detected, the failed response headers do not include X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0, but the other one does. I can't figure out why AspNetMvc is missing during the ajax call.

Comment: Make sure that all the required references for MVC 3 are installed on the new machine to which you are deploying.

Comment: I bin-deployed my project and it works when I access the initial url.  The error only when I make ajax calls.  I can see the namespace of system.web.mvc is missing in the generated code, but only for the ajax call.

Comment: This is ajax call that failed:  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetMonths")', { quarter: selectedQuarter, year: selectedYear }, function (months) {
                var monthsSelect = $('#Month');
                monthsSelect.empty();
                monthsSelect.append("<option> All Months </option>");
                $.each(months, function (index, month) {
                    monthsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: month.value,
                        text: month.text
                    }));
                });
            });